How to get the ID of the Address selected during Checkout in Salesforce B2B LWR Store
Currently, we are working on building Salesforce B2B Store using LWR Template.
I have a requirement to get some data based on the ContactPointAddress Selected during checkout.
Is there a way, to get the ID of the address (Shipping address) selected during checkout phase using the standard components in the store?
I tried some of the APIs like "Commerce Webstore Checkout"
But id only returns data related to the Address values, not the address ID.

Our goal is to use minimum customization. Using the wire adapter for "Commerce Webstore Cart", we can get the cart Id, Account details and then can create a fully Custom Shipping Address component. But then, it is not fully compatible with other standard components present on the checkout page, therefore needing for a entire customisation.
